# Storing components for an ECS in java

Tags: java, libgdx, kryonet, entity-component-system

I'm creating a networked game in java using ECS(Entity Component System) and this is my first time using ECS. I'm not sure how I should store the components though. I do want to use an Entity class where I'll store components for that specific entity but how? Should I have all components be extended from a base class and store them in an arraylist? Should I use collections? I'm basically just asking if anyone has any recommendations on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at how Unity does it. Here's a little vocabulary to help you in your research.

**Unity** uses **chunks** to store **archetypes** of components. The components are stored in memory aligned arrays inside those chunks for better cache performance.
You could also look into Unity's source code for ECS (stored in their "Entity" package), this could show you how they store and access component data.